# Problema gerando imagem JPEG de PDF com Imagick via Ghostscript

Tags: php, imagemagick

O problema é o seguinte: não gera mais imagem nenhuma... O meu script parou de funcionar, aparentemente após um update do ImageMagick. Quando busquei por respostas vi muitos se queixado de que o script parou de funcionar na mesma situação, postagens recentes deste mês ou mês passado.

Reclamei com a hospedagem, já que não tenho como ir a fundo nessa questão, já que o que converte de fato de PDF para JPEG é o Ghostscript. Eles responderam que isso é uma "questão de desenvolvimento", que não faz parte do pacote esse suporte. É isso?

A linha que gera erro é a seguinte:

```
$Img->readImage($urlArq."[".$pag."]");
```

O erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'PDFDelegateFailed `[ghostscript library] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r150x150" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 "-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-316787_tM5qhaBA3E%d" "-f/tmp/magick-316787MBoQDwPMLvz" "-f/tmp/magick-31678SNvHB_Zdq8Xt"': -dname= must be followed by a valid token @ error/pdf.c/InvokePDFDelegate/263' in /home/sintrano/public_html/conteudo_apitaco_jpeg.php:23 Stack trace: #0 /home/sintrano/public_html/conteudo_apitaco_jpeg.php(23): Imagick->readimage('apitaco/edicao-...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/sintrano/public_html/conteudo_apitaco_jpeg.php on line 23
```

A versão:

```
versionNumber: 1680
versionString: ImageMagick 6.9.0-0 Q16 x86_64 2016-05-05 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Posso dizer que eles estão tirando o corpo fora e tem que dar um jeito? Há alternativas caso eles não queiram mexer no Ghostscript já que é servidor compartilhado?

Comment: Posta o log que o PHP gera, no php.ini tem o caminho de onde é salvo o log, ou pode usar o `phpinfo()`, como o log será possivel saber aonde esta a falha. Creio eu que o problema pode ter sido com a memória excedida.

Comment: O erro que eu postei acima é o retorno do php, eu só adicionei um error_reporting e ini_set no início porque é um script pequeno que eu adicionei um "modo de teste".

Comment: Pelo que notei o servidor é linux, me diz uma coisa a a pasta esta marca como leitura e escrita?

Comment: Não tenho acesso porque é um servidor compartilhado. Mas pelos testes que eu fiz, o problema é que antes a página zero retornava a primeira página, agora tem que ser obrigatoriamente "1". Página "0" dá erro no Ghostscript e por consequência um erro fatal no Imagick.